# Breakdown of addition polymers

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

We know that condensation polymers can be broken down by hydrolysis with the elimination of small water molecules.

Then what about addition polymers? How can they be broken down into their monomers?

I think everything has their own ways to get built up, and a way to be broken down.

Comment: Hydrolysis with *addition* of water molecules. With addition polymers situation is analogous - reaction is the same as polymerisation, but backwards.

Comment: If addition polymer is polythene $\ce{(CH2CH2)_n}$, the back reaction is not exactly the contrary of the polymerization, because the polymer is a long chain like in an alcane. Water is no use and the pyrolysis produces a lot of smaller alkanes and alkenes. Of course ethene $\ce{C2H4}$ is produced, but several other simple hydrocarbons are also produced, with a number of $\ce{C}$ atoms different from $2$.